# executing function if siblings are not ":active"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would one go about executing a function if an objects siblings do not have the pseudo class ":active" using jQuery? The reason for this question is that I would like to execute that function when the cursor is hovering the certain object and NONE of its siblings are ":active" (basic meaning: I want it to execute when the mouse is hovering the object and is not clicking down on any sibling).

To get the idea:

HTML:

```
<div class="tobehovered">...</div>
<div class="sibling">...</div>
...
```

JQuery:

```
function theOneToBeExecutedOnHover(){...}
$(".tobehovered").mouseenter(function(){
  if( ... /* calculation???-ish */) theOneToBeExecutedOnHover();
}
```

The jQuery doesn't have to be formatted exactly that way. My example is just for principle.

Comment: `.sibling` is a div, so there's no `:active` for the element, you can create one if you want!

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion. If the div.sibling is clicked and held down it is then active. no?

Comment: only if its an anchor tag (`<a>`)!

Comment: You can't really check for pseudo classes in javascript, I think the closest you'll get is checking for styles set by such a pseudo class, or set a real class you can check for. Also, as noted, not all elements can be `:active`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your hovered element `$(this)`, find the siblings `.siblings()`, filter the active ones `.filter(':active')`, and check if you have none left `.length === 0`

That can be shortened like this:

```
if ($(this).siblings(':active').length === 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$(".tobehovered").mouseenter(function(event){
  if(event.target.className == 'active'){
     return;
  }

  //here execute function

}
```